# In Install4j, How can I cancel an installation in console mode?

Tags: install4j

In Install4j, How can I cancel an installation in console mode?

I want to ask the user if he wants to retry, quit or ignore.
I want the answer to be valid in console mode as well as in GUI mode.

I can check if I'm in console mode (context.isConsole()), but I can't cancel it (screen.cancel() is not relevant for console mode).

Answer (score 1):

In a "Console handler" form component, edit the "Console script" property and return false. Then the installer will be cancelled. This is also valid for the API where you can return false in overridden handleConsole() methods (for screens, actions and form components).

Comment: I'm interested in this too. We have a validation expression script (Java) that showsan optionDialog if the selected directory already exist to retry or ignore but I cant get the cancel to work in console mode either. Where would i make use of the handleConsole() method?

Comment: In the validation expression, you cannot cancel the installer, that would have to happen during the execution of an action, like in the script of a "Run script" action.